# Commisioning a pruzbul in Monsey area

Tags: product-recommendation, beit-din-court, shmita, pruzbul

What are the procedures for commissioning a *[pruzbul](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-Pruzbul.htm)*, e.g. in the greater Monsey, NY area? Are there local *batei din* or *shul* rabbis who do this? Can it be done online?

Comment: Is this a "localized" question?

Comment: relatively speaking. Not gonna accept a local bet din in Missouri but would accept online;)

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/tools/feedback_cdo/aid/5212/jewish/Fill-Out-a-Pruzbul.htm

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (Orthodox), a *prozbul* is effected as follows: Stand before three men unrelated to one another or yourself who know how a *prozbul* works and tell them that you are thereby transferring your debts to the court they comprise. (There's some standard wording found in some Rosh Hashanah prayer books and other places (doubtless including online). Use it.) They then affix their signatures to a written statement that indicates you've done so and that they're allowing you to collect the debts. (Again, there's a standard statement. Again, it's easy to find. Again, have them use it. It's short, so don't worry about its being too long to copy easily.) I believe many people rely on the oral statement alone (which suffices according to halachah) without the written statement (which serves only as proof and thus is required only if there will be some doubt as to whether a *prozbul* was effected).

But don't trust me: ask your rabbi if this is a practical question for you.